# GetClrDbg.sh returned a non-zero code: 1

Tags: docker, .net-core

I completely followed this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/docker/building-net-docker-images) to make the DotNet Core with Docker project.
However When I run the command with './dockerTask.sh build debug' , I have got an error at following point.

I spend while of day to fix this issue.Please help me..

Step 5 : RUN curl -SL ttps://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/MIEngine/getclrdbg-release/scripts/GetClrDbg.sh --output GetClrDbg.sh && chmod 700 GetClrDbg.sh && ./GetClrDbg.sh $CLRDBG_VERSION && rm GetClrDbg.sh
---> Running in 049cb0e71b0a
% Total % Received % Xferd Average Speed Time Time Time Current
Dload Upload Total Spent Left Speed
100 15024 100 15024 0 0 1862 0 0:00:08 0:00:08 --:--:-- 3318

Using arguments
Version : 'VS2015U2'
Location : ''
SkipDownloads : 'false'
LaunchClrDbgAfter : 'false'
RemoveExistingOnUpgrade : 'false'
Info: Using clrdbg version '15.0.26022.0'
Info: Previous installation at not found
Error: Install location is not set
**ERROR: Service 'api' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c curl -SL ttps://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/MIEngine/getclrdbg-release/scripts/GetClrDbg.sh --output GetClrDbg.sh && chmod 700 GetClrDbg.sh && ./GetClrDbg.sh $CLRDBG_VERSION && rm GetClrDbg.sh' returned a non-zero code: 1**

I have updated brew and dotnet core SDK.

Thank you for any further helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been fixed.
Actually, this issue is a bug which is Microsoft/MIEngine side.
https://github.com/Microsoft/MIEngine/issues/531

Thank you for fixing this problem :)
for persons who have same issue. 
just download the latest source code then it should be fixed.